# Waiting for death or Waiting to die

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct to say?

"He is waiting for death"
or
"He is waiting to die"

"for" or "to" ?

If either is correct, give me some examples. I have a doubt where exactly I can use "for" and "to"

Comment: What do you think the difference in meaning is? Why do you think this? Have you done any research? ELL isn't a proofreading site or a dictionary, so you should add additional information/context to your question.

Comment: I have edited the question. Now ok @LMS ?

Comment: What meaning do you wish to get as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait for + noun. To wait for time, death, life, bananas, whatever.

To wait for + specific noun. To wait for the train, the plane, my aunt.

**You wait for some thing or situation**.

Wait to + verb. Waiting to leave, shop, play, hang out.

**You wait to do something**.

Comment: So, in conclusion, either one could be correct.

Comment: They mean different things. Yes, both are correct.